# Node.js: how to create a simple Duplex stream just to pipe?

Tags: node.js, node-streams

1. I have a `Writable` stream
2. I need to pass it to a function
3. the function closes the `Write` stream it receives in input
4. I need my `Writable` stream still open after the function execution

```js
const stream: Writable = ...; // my Writable stream

closingFunction(stream); // this function closes the stream it receives in input
console.log(stream.writable); // false: the stream was closed by closingFunction
```

So easy! I just need a 'pipe' stream, pipe it to my stream (with `end` option set to `false`) and passing it to the function (as side effect it also closes the pipe for me!), but...

but I'm not able to find nothing already built in to perform this stupid task. :(

As a workaround I had to wrote my own stupid 'pipe' stream:

```js
const stream: Writable = ...; // my Writable stream

// My simple, incomplete solution
const pipe = new Duplex({
  read: function(this: Duplex & { chunks: unknown[] }) {
    if(this.chunks) this.push(this.chunks.shift());
  },
  write: function(this: Duplex & { chunks: unknown[] }, chunk: Buffer, encoding, callback) {
    if(! this.chunks) this.chunks = [];
    this.chunks.push(chunk);
    callback(null);
  }
});

pipe.pipe(stream, { end: false }); // pipe without closing the target stream on end

closingFunction(pipe); // this function closes the pipe for me
console.log(pipe.writable); // false: the pipe was closed
console.log(stream.writable); // true: the stream is still open
```

Ok, this works but the simple 'pipe' stream I wrote is too much simple, not optimized and it doesn't checks for errors.

**Is there something already built in which solves my simple problem saving me the time to write a completely correct `Duplex` stream?**

P.S.: the example source is in **TypeScript**, an answer in **JavaScript** would be fine as well

Answer (score 1):

After some more researches I found [`stream.PassThrough`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#class-streampassthrough)...

> The `stream.PassThrough` class is a trivial implementation of a Transform stream that simply passes the input bytes across to the output.

... it seems to be exactly what I was looking for...

> Its purpose is primarily for examples and testing, but there are some use cases where `stream.PassThrough` is useful as a building block for novel sorts of streams.

... and this seems to be one of those cases.

```js
const stream: Writable = ...; // my Writable stream
const pipe = new PassThrough(); // simply...

pipe.pipe(stream, { end: false }); // pipe without closing the target stream on end
closingFunction(pipe); // this function closes the pipe for me

console.log(pipe.writable); // false: the pipe was closed
console.log(stream.writable); // true: the stream is still open
```

It actually works.

Comment: This answer was flagged and marked once for deletion  "as low-quality because of its **length** and/or content.". Please expand it a bit so that others, not only you,  may quickly understand it.